# Word Imposters - Which Does Not Belong?

Tags: word, enigmatic-puzzle

> Here we have:
>
> Elizabeth, Charlemagne, Antoinette, Alexander,
>
> Tutankhamun, Napoleon, Tamerlane, Hammurabi,
>
> Suleiman, Augustus, Chandragupta, Nefertiti,
>
> Cleopatra, Boudicca, Zenobia, Leonidas,
>
> Demosthenes, Pisistratus, Amenhotep, and Akhenaten.

All of them are correct, except for one. Which one does not belong, and why?

Comment: Just to check: one out of all 20 is incorrect, or one out of each group of 4?

Comment: Is the Knowledge tag necessary? I do not know some of the names.

Comment: @Drd Without saying too much, no...

Comment: @Stiv one out of the 20 is incorrect.

Comment: All of them were kings/queens except for Demosthenes?

Comment: @CBredlow Well, technically Napoleon was never king, but rather a de facto leader who acted as king.

Comment: @Dopplegamer and Suleiman was a Shah

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps the imposter is

> Antoinette

> Because every other person has exactly 4 vowels in their name.
>  Antoinette however, has 5 vowels but tried to slip in to the party!
>  Also noting that there are FIVE groups of FOUR, as validation.

Comment: The fact that I used historical names for the words really threw some people off. Good job!